# panda install error on mac because of existing numpy

Tags: python, pandas

I installed pip to my MacBook Air manually by `sudo python get-pip.py`.
and have tried to install pandas by `sudo -Hi pip install pandas` but got this:

(Note: I checked the other similar questions but my problem is different.)

`$ sudo -Hi pip install pandas
Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-0.22.0-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from pandas)
Collecting numpy>=1.9.0 (from pandas)
  Using cached numpy-1.14.0-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from pandas)
Installing collected packages: numpy, pandas
  Found existing installation: numpy 1.8.0rc1
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (numpy) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling numpy-1.8.0rc1:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-FbYaYw-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy-1.8.0rc1-py2.7.egg-info'`

How can I fix this?

Comment: You should probably consider something like anaconda anyway, but at the very least use virtual environments. Just install fresh numpy/pandas http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: I assumed that python env can be easily set on any platform but it seems it's not. I will try anaconda. but I will open this question for a while because I really want to know how to figure this out. Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: virtualenvs definitely work in Mac OS. There should be no problem.